# Split values in arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have a Long string from that I want to store the keyword in array or collection, the format of my string is like below:

**Title:** My Test Page Title.

**Desc:** My page description.

***Keywords***: Bessel function, legendre function, Differential Equations, Bessel, Legendre, Homogenous, Assignment & Maths Homework Help.

**Bessel & Legendre Function:**

Homogenous Equations of the second order of the type 
  + x + ( - )y = 0, v  [0,  ), x  [0,  )………………….(1)
(1 -  )   - 2x  + n (n + 1)y = 0, n = 1, 2 ……, x (-1, 1)…………………(2)

In this String I want to store all Keywords in Array/collection split from comma.
My problem is that How I can find out the starting and ending point to split the keywords, I can get the **Starting point** from ***Keywords***: but what should be my ending point to store the keyword in array/collection, there is no any fix format,
there is only one fix format which is there will be a Para after ending the Keyword section.

any one can suggest me regular expression for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there will be a Para

Seems like you should first split the string into lines.

And then the line that starts with **Keywords:** holds your keywords.

You can use the `string.Split()` method to split into lines as well as for breaking out the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like the Keywords section ends with a fullstop. So you could find the next fullstop ie IndexOf(".") after the "Keywords:" ....

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do:

```
string afterKeywords = data.Substring(data.IndexOf("Keywords:") + 9);
string beforeNextPara = afterKeywords.Substring(0, afterKeywords.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine));
var dataWeNeed = beforeNextPara.Split(',');
```